# How to plot ROC and Recall-precision curves for this obtained data

Tags: r, caret, precision-recall

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have this obtained data : ( I had trained a SOM map from scratch then i used a number of epochs, Each epoch consist of a number of iterations ) :

```
Recall=c(0, 0.805, 0.805, 0.805, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.815, 0.82, 0.82, 
0.825, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.84, 0.845, 0.845, 0.845, 0.845, 0.85, 
0.855, 0.855, 0.855, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.855, 0.855, 0.85, 0.855, 
0.855, 0.86, 0.865, 0.865, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 
0.86, 0.86, 0.865, 0.865, 0.865, 0.865, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.875, 
0.875, 0.88, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.895, 0.895, 0.9, 
0.905, 0.905, 0.905, 0.905, 0.905, 0.91, 0.905, 0.91, 0.915, 
0.915, 0.915, 0.915, 0.92, 0.925, 0.925, 0.925, 0.925, 0.925, 
0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.935, 
0.935, 0.945, 0.95, 0.95, 0.955, 0.955, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96
)

Precision=c(0, 0.7, 0.706140350877193, 0.706140350877193, 0.707423580786026, 
0.707423580786026, 0.710526315789474, 0.7117903930131, 0.71304347826087, 
0.716157205240175, 0.717391304347826, 0.718614718614719, 0.721739130434783, 
0.721739130434783, 0.724137931034483, 0.725321888412017, 0.725321888412017, 
0.728448275862069, 0.728448275862069, 0.735930735930736, 0.737068965517241, 
0.737068965517241, 0.74025974025974, 0.74235807860262, 0.745614035087719, 
0.745614035087719, 0.746724890829694, 0.746724890829694, 0.745614035087719, 
0.746724890829694, 0.743478260869565, 0.744588744588745, 0.745689655172414, 
0.748917748917749, 0.747826086956522, 0.747826086956522, 0.747826086956522, 
0.747826086956522, 0.747826086956522, 0.751091703056769, 0.754385964912281, 
0.754385964912281, 0.755458515283843, 0.758771929824561, 0.762114537444934, 
0.762114537444934, 0.766519823788546, 0.766519823788546, 0.766519823788546, 
0.767543859649123, 0.767543859649123, 0.765217391304348, 0.763948497854077, 
0.763948497854077, 0.763948497854077, 0.763948497854077, 0.763948497854077, 
0.764957264957265, 0.764957264957265, 0.765957446808511, 0.766949152542373, 
0.766949152542373, 0.766949152542373, 0.766949152542373, 0.763713080168776, 
0.764705882352941, 0.763713080168776, 0.764705882352941, 0.7625, 
0.7625, 0.765690376569038, 0.765690376569038, 0.766666666666667, 
0.767634854771784, 0.767634854771784, 0.770833333333333, 0.774058577405858, 
0.774058577405858, 0.773109243697479, 0.769874476987448, 0.766666666666667, 
0.766666666666667, 0.766666666666667, 0.766666666666667, 0.768595041322314, 
0.770491803278688, 0.770491803278688, 0.770491803278688, 0.772727272727273, 
0.772727272727273, 0.777777777777778, 0.775510204081633, 0.775510204081633, 
0.773279352226721, 0.773279352226721, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 0.774193548387097, 
0.774193548387097)
```

First , i'm wanting to plot the Recall-Precision curve :

```
library(ggplot2)
df=data.frame("Recall"=Recall, "Precision"=Precision) 

ggplot(df, aes(Recall,Precision)) + geom_point(size=3) + geom_smooth() + theme_minimal()
```

This gives the following plot :

[image: My obtained plot]

However i noticed that many `Recall-Precision` looks something like [source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html):

[image]
[image]

In fact , the curves usually starts by `(1,0)` then ends in `(0,1)`.
However , my plot started from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)`.

I'm wanting to know what could be the wrong thing i did !

Thank you for help !

Comment: The obtained values of recall and precision are recorded in a number of iterations ( For example : each 10 iterations )

Comment: could someone help ?